# Virtual networking with VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualization, static-ip

I have a question about virtual networking. I want to create a virtual network between two virtual machines and the host OS. The problem occurs when i try to change manually the ips of the virtual machines: if I set a static ip for the virtual machines the internet connection, on those machines, won't work (but they can communicate each other: i've tested it using the "ping command").
So, my question is: is there someone that can explain me, step by step, a way to configure static ips for the virtual machines in virtualbox and to connect them each other (also with the Host)?

I'm forgotten to say the the host OS is ubuntu (karmik koala) and the two virtual machines are windows XP and windows server 2008

Answer (score 1):

I think your virtual machines are in "Host-only networking" mode.

Change it into "Bridge Networking" mode so that you can make communication between virtual machines, host and external network.

Comment: It won't work even in Bridge Networking mode

Comment: check this link. http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Comment: In addition to having all the NICs in "Bridge" mode, they also need to be assigned onto compatible IP addressing plans as well. What are the IP addressing configurations/assignments for each NIC?